# Error while flashing CM 11 ROM on HTC One M7

Tags: cyanogenmod, rooting, clockworkmod-recovery

I am trying to flash my HTC One M7. I bought this device from T-Mobile.

I am using ClockworkMod Recovery v6.0.4.8 (recovery-clockwork-6.0.4.8-m7.img). However, whenever I try to flash anything, it give me an error. I am using Cyanogenmod snapshot build (cm-11-20141112-SNAPSHOT-M12-m7.zip).

Steps I am following:

1. Wipe data/factory reset -> Yes - wipe all user data
2. install zip -> install from sdcard -> select the zip file

Log:

> Finding update package... 
>   Opening update package...
>   Installing
>   update... Installation aborted.

I get same error whenever I try to flash anything. Either it being UPDATE-SuperSU-v2.zip or GAAPPS. I have also tried TWRP (twrp-2.8.6.0-m7.img) still same error.

I am following the instructions from here: wiki.cyanogenmod.org/w/Install_CM_for_m7

What's might be reason for it or where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the issue. It was due to safari auto-unzip file after download. I was making a zip of the file again.

I used chrome to download the file and voila it worked perfectly.